# TD Ameritrade API unable get the Access/Refresh token to work

Tags: api, rest

I have been trying unsuccessfully for a couple of days to call the TD Ameritrade api to get an access/refresh token.  I am getting the error "The API key in request is either null or blank or invalid."

I created the App on their site and it says status approved.  I

I am 100% my redirect_uri is correct and encoded (I have been trying to get this to work for 2 nights now)  In my app, it is "http://127.0.0.1"  I am also sure I am not misspelling my Consumer Key.  I have verified these against my app numerous times.

This is the URL I tried in Postman:

[https://auth.tdameritrade.com/auth?response_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1&client_id={{My](https://auth.tdameritrade.com/auth?response_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1&client_id=%7B%7BMy) CONSUMER KEY}}%040AMER.OAUTHAP

I have also tried it in Python:

```
import requests

MYCLIENT_ID='...'

headers =  {"Content-Type":"application/json"}

r = requests.post(
    'https://api.tdameritrade.com/v1/oauth2/token',
    data={
        'response_type': 'code',
        'client_id': MYCLIENT_ID,
      'redirect_uri' : 'http://127.0.0.1',
    }, headers = headers
)
r.json()
```

{'error': 'The API key in request is either null or blank or invalid.'}

Tried calling the TD Ameritrade API to get an access token.

Comment: I might have figured it out.

Comment: Hi, Walt, did you figure it out? Please, reply.

Comment: Yes please let us know the solution ( I have the same problem). Pleas post an answer here ad describe your solution in detail. May thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I have opened a dev account at Ameritrade and implemented various gets (e.g, share price) to the dev account.
Now I have opened a "real" trading account at Ameritrade and tried to get "the real access" (place buy and sell orders, get account information's and so on).
It's very complicate (and bad documented) to be able to get the "real access" to the account - therefore an short description to the hurdles:

First you have to create a dev account and generate "**consumer key"**

- This consumer key then (fortunately) should not change
- **Important:** Put htt**p**://127.0.0.1 as redirect address (not https)

Then, you have to generate **"base code"** (attention! **only 30 minutes valid**).
Call:
https://auth.tdameritrade.com/auth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1&client_id=HV444VTH7GJ4FSMSIO8IKLXTPYJW%40AMER.OAUTHAP
in a browser
where redirect address has to be the encoded redirect address stored in your dev account and client_id has to be your encoded consumer key **+ @AMER.OAUTHAP (encoded)**
If you call that link and anything is correct, you  will see the Ameritrade login form and have to login and grant your app (from dev account) the rights.
Then you will see an error page (that's normal) and manually have to copy the "base key" in the url bar (is returned there) and extract the code (after "code=").
Then you have to **decode** the base code here:
https://www.urlencoder.org/

Then, you have to to generate a **"refresh token"** **within 30 Minutes!** here:
https://developer.tdameritrade.com/authentication/apis/post/token-0
Put in:
the text "authorization_code" in the field "grant_type"
the text "offline" in the field "access_type"
your consumer key **+ @AMER.OAUTHAP** in the field "client_id"
your redirect url (as stored in the dev account) in the field "redirect_url"
Press "Send"
The copy your **"refresh token"** from the response
**Fortunately the refresh token then is valid for 90 days**

Now, I have to implement to get an **"access token"** in my app, as an access token is needed to get the "real access" **and an access token is only valid for 30 minutes!**
It definitely make no sense to do this manually...
Therefore , I have to implement a timer, that gets a new access token from the refresh token any 25 minutes.

**To get an "access token" over the API has not worked and I have tried various "solutions" for days now. By my various searches, I also found this page and therefore post here...**

**---- In my case the problem was: ----**

```
 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

As descriped above, I have implemented various API calls (e.g. get quotes) with the dev code (consumerkey) and "application/json" to the url: https://api.tdameritrade.com/v1/
Anything has worked as expected.

It seems as the **authentication url**: https://api.tdameritrade.com/v1/oauth2/token
in **difference** mandatory needs **Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded**

So relevant code snippets:
Generating the json request:

```
dim cpostAccessCode as string:
cpostAccessCode = "grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=" + AmeriTradeRefreshTokenEncoded + "&access_type=&code=&client_id=" + AmeriTradeConsumerKeyEncoded + "&redirect_uri="
```

Whereby AmeriTradeRefreshTokenEncoded contains the **encoded** refresh token and AmeriTradeConsumerKeyEncoded contains the **encoded** consumer key.

Call (with application/x-www-form-urlencoded):

```
Dim response As System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage = Await oHTTP_Client.PostAsync(cAurufURL, New StringContent(cpostAccessCode, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"))
```

**This now works in my app.**
Note: It should be possible to also get the refresh token over the API (I will implement that, it possible).

The "workflow" to hold the API "alive" then will be:
1.) Any 85 days (only valid for 90 days): get a new "base code" over the web client (I see no chance to automate this)
2.) Within 30 minutes after 1.): Get a new "refresh token" from the base code (I hope, I will be able to automate this)
3.) Store the new "refresh token" in a database as base to get a new "access token" over the API any 25 minutes (see above)
4.) at 3.) also store a timestamp (actual date + 85 days) and set an alert in the app as soon the timestamp is reached (I then have 5 days time to get a new "base code" -> 1.))

**Hope this helps somebody to save a lot of time...**

Answer (score 0):

In python:

```
import requests
url = 'https://api.tdameritrade.com/v1/oauth2/token'
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
payload = 'grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=<YOUR_TOKEN_HERE>&access_type=&code=&client_id=<YOUR_CLIENT_IH_HERE>&redirect_uri='
r = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
print(r.json()["access_token"])
```